spresense SDKのconfig.hが見つからない、その上コンパイラパスが通らない
開発環境 Windows10 msys2にSDKを以下のサイトを参考にして導入して開発。
https://developer.sony.com/spresense/development-guides/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html
spresenseをspresense SDKを用いて開発を行おうと、環境構築をしていたのだが、サンプルコードの<nuttx/config.h>がmsys2のフォルダ内のどこにも存在せず、そもそもnuttxフォルダの中に何もない。
どうしたらよいでしょうか。


includeしている"nuttx/config.h"はSpresenseSDKのソースコードをdownloadしたままでは存在しないようです。確認したら、SDKコンフィグの実施後に、nuttx/include/config.hが生成されています。
自分のところでは、以下のMSYS2環境の構成で、SDKコンフィグ実施後生成されました。
（MSYS2環境はビルド遅いので普段はWSL2環境を使っていますが・・）
・MSYS2(mmsys2-x86_64-20240507.exe)
・VSCode(x64): 1.90.0
・Spresense VSCode IDE：1.5.100
・spresense-sdk：v3.2.0
SDKコンフィグ時にエラー発生しているとかでしょうか？
または、そもそもgit clone時に"--recursive"オプション付け忘れて、spresense-nuttxのsubmoduleが存在していないとかはないでしょうか？　
そのケースかどうかは、"git submodule"でnuttxのコードが存在しているかで確認できると思います。SDKv3.2.0のコードだと正しくsubmoduleが落とせていると以下のように見えると思います。

$ git submodule
 fe8ed90abc356347378eb25e2586e90df7be015a externals/micro-ecc/micro-ecc (v1.1-6-gfe8ed90)
 020b13cb57f0baed5c3988e520788de4be48e6b1 externals/mossfw/mossfw (heads/main)
 6bfa72b8c47cd5621e1f211d3e58ba63a1f5000f externals/nnablart/nnabla-c-runtime (v1.24.0)
 04159c3e30f9d9f2d8453b55b99a544e3c0b4242 nuttx (nuttx-11.0.0-6450-g04159c3e30)
 1394db37df059b375169fc409affb8f67b214d23 sdk/apps (nuttx-11.0.0-1684-g1394db37d)

一度確認してみてください。
